# Display Serial number in datagridview (DESC order) C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, row

I want to display row number in datagridview as DESC ORDER.

I use following code in "RowPostPaint Event" to Display Serial number in datagridview.

```
        DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
        System.Drawing.Font rowFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, Convert.ToByte(0));

        dynamic centerFormat = new StringFormat();
        centerFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        centerFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        string rowIdx = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
        Rectangle headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, rowFont, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
```

> **Code Above gives Following Result**

1
2
3
.
.
10

[Screen Short 1 - Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9wAD.png)

> **Image Below is a sample of what I want**

10
9
8
7
.
.
1

[Screen Short 2 - A sample of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA7Ff.png)

The first method is depended On "RowIndex" . is there any way to do this using "RowCount" or something like that.

I want to display serial number in Descending Order Like Second Image.How to do this...?

Comment: Check out : https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+how+to+sort+datagridview

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by subtract `grid.Rows.Count` and `e.RowIndex`.

Please refer the below code.

```
DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
        System.Drawing.Font rowFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, Convert.ToByte(0));

        dynamic centerFormat = new StringFormat();
        centerFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        centerFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        string rowIdx = (grid.Rows.Count - e.RowIndex).ToString(); //you can get the row count and subtract it.
        Rectangle headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, rowFont, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
```